# Installation problem downloading language package

Tags: 12.04

I am installing ubuntu 12.04 version.
All i have done partition and also made user name and password but its downloading language pack for 2 hours what i have to do now?

Comment: Seems like it's got stuck. Try rebooting and see if it picks up from where it got stuck. if not, I'd start  afresh and reformat if possible.

Answer (score 0):

1.If ur internet connection is not slow enough..... try to disconnect and reconnect ur network from the menu available at top right corner of installer screen

1. If the internet is slow and there is no option to skip the download. Then abort the installation totally and start a fresh one.

For the next time when u are installing ubuntu....

1.**opt for not to connect to any available network**

2.**opt for not to download updates during installation**